# Setup Google Analytics with Codename One

Tags: google-analytics, codenameone

How to setup Google Analytics with Codename One?
I tried using the [analytics service](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/analytics/AnalyticsService.html), after creating a property and getting an agent string, I added:

```
    AnalyticsService.init("UA-something-here", "property name");
    AnalyticsService.setAppsMode(true);
```

but it did not start tracking. In the Codename One article, it is written that I need agent string and domain string. Are domain and property the same? How do I setup Google Analytics with Codename One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agent string is the "UA-......." number, and the domain string is "apppackagename.companyname.com"

Comment: Yes. I'd also mention that you need to invoke the visit method if the application isn't an old GUI builder application

Comment: What is my apppackagename? Is it the package where the main class is located? Would you give an example if I just create a app with defaults (main package name is MyApplication in package  com.mycompany.myapp). I tried "myapp.mycompany.com" and it did not work. I am using the old GUI builder.

Comment: I did what you did and it is working for me, did you add some calls to the visit method?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake